# Optimizing memoization in compiled Mathematica code

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, memoization

Consider the following two codes - `compiledcode` and `compiledcode1`:

```
tab1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^4, 2}];
tab2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^3, 68}];

compiledcode = 
  Compile[{{tab1, _Real, 1}, {tab2, _Real, 2}}, 
   Module[{acc = 0., val1, val2, val3 = 0., len = Length[tab2], 
     len1 = Length[tab2[[1]]], val4 = 0., cond = 0., condval3 = 0., 
     condval4 = 0.}, val1 = Compile`GetElement[tab1, 1];
    val2 = Compile`GetElement[tab1, 2];
    Do[cond = 0.;
     Do[val3 = val1*val2*Compile`GetElement[tab2, i, j];
      condval3 = Boole[val3*val2 > 0.6];
      If[condval3 == 1., Do[val4 = Compile`GetElement[tab2, i, j + k];
         condval4 = Boole[val4*val2 > 0.6];
         If[condval4 == 1., cond = Boole[val4*val3 > 0.6]];
         If[cond == 1., Break[]];, {k, 1, len1 - j}];];
      If[cond == 1., Break[]];, {j, 1, len1 - 1, 1}];
     acc += cond;, {i, 1, len}];
    acc/len], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
```

```
compiledcode1 = 
  Compile[{{tab1, _Real, 1}, {tab2, _Real, 2}}, 
   Module[{acc = 0., val1, val2, val3 = 0., len = Length[tab2], 
     len1 = Length[tab2[[1]]], val4 = 0., cond = 0., condval3 = 0., 
     condval4 = 0., condval4Array, condval4Array1}, 
    condval4Array = Table[1., len1];
    val1 = Compile`GetElement[tab1, 1];
    val2 = Compile`GetElement[tab1, 2];
    Do[cond = 0.;
     condval4Array1 = condval4Array;
     Do[
      If[Compile`GetElement[condval4Array1, j] == 1., 
       val3 = val1*val2*Compile`GetElement[tab2, i, j];
       condval3 = Boole[val3*val2 > 0.6];
       If[condval3 == 1.,
        Do[
          val4 = Compile`GetElement[tab2, i, j + k];
          condval4 = Boole[val4*val2 > 0.6];
          If[condval4 == 0., condval4Array1[[j + k]] = 0.];
          If[condval4 == 1., cond = Boole[val4*val3 > 0.6]];
          If[cond == 1., Break[]];
          , {k, 1, len1 - j}];];
       If[cond == 1., Break[]];]
      , {j, 1, len1 - 1, 1}];
     acc += cond;, {i, 1, len}];
    acc/len], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
```

They both iterate over possible column combinations of `tab2`: `j`th and `j+k`th, with `k > 0`, and evaluate some condition only if the first and then the second loop iteration meets some conditions `condval3` and `condval4` correspondingly (they are the same for both loops).

The difference is that `compiledcode1` calls multiple times the list `condval4array1`, whose purpose is memorizing the values of `condval4`, such that there is no need to iterate over `j` for which `condval4 = 0`.

Of course, for this toy example, `compiledcode1` is slower due to multiple using of `CopyTensor`:

```
pt = compiledcode[tab1, tab2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
pt1 = compiledcode1[tab1, tab2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
pt==pt1
```

> 0.37
>
> 0.65
>
> True

However, in my real case, I am dealing with much more time-consuming evaluations, and it becomes crucial not to iterate if it is possible. With the implementation as in `compiledcode1`, the "memoized" version of the compiled code becomes slightly faster than the "non-memoized".

Is it possible to further improve the memoization algorithm to reach an even better speedup?

**Edit**

I made a simple improvement motivated by the fact that the most time-consuming action is `CopyTensor`: the string `condval4Array1 = condval4Array;` is evaluated only if there has been at least one change in `condval4Array1` inside the loop:

```
compiledcode2 = 
  Compile[{{tab1, _Real, 1}, {tab2, _Real, 2}}, 
   Module[{acc = 0., val1, val2, val3 = 0., len = Length[tab2], 
     len1 = Length[tab2[[1]]], val4 = 0., cond = 0., condval3 = 0., 
     condval4 = 0., condval4Array, condval4Array1, jth = 0},
    condval4Array = condval4Array1 = Table[1., len1];
    val1 = Compile`GetElement[tab1, 1];
    val2 = Compile`GetElement[tab1, 2];
    Do[cond = 0.;
     If[jth > 0, condval4Array1 = condval4Array];
     jth = 0;
     Do[
      If[Compile`GetElement[condval4Array1, j] == 1., 
       val3 = val1*val2*Compile`GetElement[tab2, i, j];
       condval3 = Boole[val3*val2 > 0.6];
       If[condval3 == 1.,
        Do[
          val4 = Compile`GetElement[tab2, i, j + k];
          condval4 = Boole[val4*val2 > 0.6];
          If[condval4 == 0., jth += 1; condval4Array1[[j + k]] = 0.];
          If[condval4 == 1., cond = Boole[val4*val3 > 0.6]];
          If[cond == 1., Break[]];
          , {k, 1, len1 - j}];];
       If[cond == 1., Break[]];]
      , {j, 1, len1 - 1, 1}];
     acc += cond;, {i, 1, len}];
    acc/len], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
```

It is faster than `compiledcode1`:

```
t = t1 = t2 = {};
Do[
 tab1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^4, 2}];
 tab2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^3, 68}];
 pt = compiledcode[tab1, tab2] // RepeatedTiming // First;
 pt1 = compiledcode1[tab1, tab2] // RepeatedTiming // First;
 pt2 = compiledcode2[tab1, tab2] // RepeatedTiming // First;
 (*pt==pt1\[Equal]pt2*)
 t = Join[t, {pt}];
 t1 = Join[t1, {pt1}];
 t2 = Join[t2, {pt2}];
 , {i, 1, 10, 1}]
{t // Mean, t1 // Mean, t2 // Mean}
```

> {0.42, 0.60, 0.53}

Now, in my real case, the speedup becomes significant. However, still, I am wondering whether there exists another way of memorizing inside `Compile` that does not involve `CopyTensor`.

Comment: Is this really the _minimal_ working example for your problem?

Comment: @Domen : yes, I think so. It deals with a mother table `tab1` and computes for each row some averaged value from `tab2`. I have not found a simpler example without allowing too much simplifications.

Comment: @Domen : the real case also does not use just the elements of the tables, it instead computes some quantities which enter the Boolean conditions.